# Having trouble with device or resource busy error in aircrack-ng; raspberry pi 3, raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I was using my raspberry pi 3 today trying to launch a deauth attack using aircrack-ng(Don't worry the network is mine). But I'm not here to talk about hacking I actually need help with setting up wlan0 and mon0. When I type in the following command this is what happens:

```
    sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 11
    Error for wireless request "Set Frequency" (8B04) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Device or resource busy.
```

Now I've heard there is a daemon that prevents the usage of this command; ifplugd, but when I try to stop the service it does this...

```
    sudo service ifplugd stop
    ifplugd: unrecognized service
```

So that doesn't work...but I think it should; when I go to the etc directory ifplugd is right there it even has its own sub-directory, I don't know what's wrong someone please help...

Comment: Are you attempting to use internal wifi or a USB wifi card?

Comment: USB wifi....I have a WiPi

Comment: can I have a link to the product page?

Comment: I got it a store but here's the online link: http://www.newark.com/element14/wipi/wlan-module-for-the-raspberry/dp/07W8938

Answer (score 1):

`ifplugd` has nothing to do with WiFi. If you want to get exclusive access to a wireless adapter, you should rather run

```
sudo service wpa_supplicant stop
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop offending processes, as root `airmon-ng check kill`. It is usually something automagic, like dhclient or wpa_supplicant, and it may try to restart, so begin your aireplay-ng session immediately after doing this.